# How can I make the KDE file selector dialog recognize *.m4a files as "media"?

Tags: kde, media

In KDE, when browsing for a media file in the file selector dialog, ***.m4a** files aren't showing up with the **Media** filter applied:

[image]

If I remove the 'Media' filter, the ***.m4a** file shows up:

[image]

How can I get this dialog to recognize ***.m4a** as a Media file extension?

I verified that ***.m4a** is registered as an extension for MPEG4 audio in System settings--and as you can see from the second screen shot, KDE does think the ***.m4a** file is a media file, as represented by the musical note icon.  Google mostly points to problems with Amarok, which of course I'm not using here.

---

System details:
Debian 7.8
KDE 4.8

Comment: This smells bug to me. :( Try https://bugs.kde.org/ ?

Comment: The same thing happens with *.spx files, FWIW.

Answer (score 0):

In unix the file's extension does not determine the it's type . each file has a magic number that determines it's type . you can see the file's type with the command "file" as in "$ file example.m4a" . This shows the file's true type . You can test this if you renamed any txt file to "exampletxt.m4a" and you'll find the KDE automatically change it's icon but when you use the file command on it "$ file exampletxt.m4a" you'll see it's true type. Anyway, KDE keeps the known typs in System settings ==> File Association . under audio list click on mp4 and see the filename patterns list and if *.m4a doesn't exist, add it.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I did this first. `I verified that .m4a is registered as an extension for MPEG4 audio in System settings--and as you can see from the second screen shot, KDE does think the .m4a file is a media file`